# How to set up a Category based recommendations in Einstein recommendation in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

In Marketing cloud I want to use Einstein web recommendations with a product webshop. Products on a webshop are segmented in product categories, subcategories and subsubcategories. Example of these could be:

- Category: Home_appliances
- Subcategory of Home_appliances: Refridgerators
- SubSubcategory of Home_appliances/Refridgerators: Retro_refridgerators

**Question for setting the Product catalog attributes in Einstein web recommendations:**
Are there any naming convention rules on how to set the product catalog attributes for the Category, Subcategory and Subsubcategory? Can for the category be used the default ProductType attribute? What I gathered from different sources is that it could be any attribute name as long as the values that are pushed via collect code match the values in any of the attributes in the catalog.

This means I could use default "ProductType" attribute for categories and add let's say "Subcategroy" custom attribute for subcategories and "SubSubcategory" custom attribute for subsubcategories.

Is this correct setup of the catalog or should there be some defined names for the product catalog attributes for categories, subcategories and subsubcategories?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community done